# how to center a character in a css3 div with rounded borders

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

Hey I hope you can help me. I am trying to center a number in a css3-div. I am using this:

```
border:2px solid #333333;  
padding:1px;  
-moz-border-radius:10px;  
-webkit-border-radius:10px;  
-o-border-radius:10px;  
-khtml-border-radius:10px;  
border-radius:10px;  
background-color: #fff;  
height: 25px;  
width: 25px;
```

and it gives me this:

[image]

How do I center it also with a single-digit charachter?

many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the element is also `display: block;` (or `display: inline-block;`) you can just add:

```
text-align: center;
line-height: 25px; /* vertical height of the container/element */
```

to your CSS.